# How do I pass my proxy credentials to a SharePoint Client Context object...? (SharePoint Client Object Model)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm writing an application that accesses a SharePoint site using the Client Object Model and I'm behind a proxy server.

I call...

```
ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

and receive the following error message...

*The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.*

How do I pass my proxy credentials to the Client Context object...?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to pass the WebProxy (System.Net.WebProxy) object to the WebRequest instance executing your query. One way of doing this is

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("<a valid url>");
context.ExecutingWebRequest += (sen, args) =>
{
  WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
  myProxy.Address = new Uri("http://<proxy_server_address>");

  myProxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("jack_reacher","<password>", "<domain>");
  args.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Proxy = myProxy;
};
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Edit: Fixed typo (ags --> args)

Answer (score 4):

I think you need the following in your app.config inside the `<configuration>` node:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your app.config if your proxy server doesn't require authentication:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy
       usesystemdefault="False"
       proxyaddress="http://myproxyserver.company.com:8080"
       bypassonlocal="True"
     />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```